# Procfile for Heroku for Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

In all the tutorials I found they suggested to create the `Procfile` to deploy to heroku with the following line:

```
web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi --log-file -
```

Since I'm using Django 1.8 and in setting.py I have this:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProjectName.wsgi.application'
```

I thought this would work:

```
web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi.application --log-file -
```

but it didn't, an error was `ImportError: No module named application`

Comment: hmm.... could you share your `wsgi.py` file :)

Comment: @Yeo, I don't know....

Answer (score 15):

Very close! What you need is:

```
web: gunicorn ProjectName.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

Note the colon, instead of a dot.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Where did you find it? I was having the same problem.

Comment: Ok, found it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn. Only strange thing now is I had to run heroku ps:scale web=1 to make gunicorn start in Heroku. It wasn't enough with the Procfile